# switch columns conditionally on certain column value

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to switch column `B` and `C` conditional on column `ID`; only switch when `ID = N`. My following code works, but is there a simpler/intuitive method?

```
df
ID   A   B   C
Y    4   2   4
Y    1   5   7
N    8   3   NaN
N    6   2   NaN

Expected df
ID   A   B   C
Y    4   2   4
Y    1   5   7
N    8   NaN 3  
N    6   NaN 2
```

```
df$Bnew <- ifelse(df$ID== "N", df$C, df$B)
df$Cnew <- ifelse(df$ID== "N", df$B, df$C)
drops <- c("B", "C")
df <- df[, !names(df) %in% drops]
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "Bnew"] <- "B"
colnames(df)[colnames(df) == "Cnew"] <- "C"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch the columns when the condition is met.

```
df[df$ID == "N", c("B", "C")] <- df[df$ID == "N", c("C", "B")]
```